# How to enumerate frameboxes?

Tags: pdftex, enumerate, framed

I have a number of frameboxes. How to enumerate those frameboxes?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,amssymb}
% Allow Unicode input (alternatively, you can use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX)
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{microtype,xparse,tcolorbox}
\newenvironment{reviewer-comment }{}{}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\tcolorboxenvironment{reviewer-comment }{empty,
  left = 1em, top = 1ex, bottom = 1ex,
  borderline west = {2pt} {0pt} {black!20},
}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment {response} { +m O{black!20} } {
  \IfValueT {#1} {
    \begin{reviewer-comment~}
      \setlength\parindent{2em}
      \noindent
      \ttfamily #1
    \end{reviewer-comment~}
  }
  \par\noindent\ignorespaces
} { \bigskip\par }

\NewDocumentCommand \Reviewer { m } {
  \section*{Comments~by~Reviewer~#1}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\AtBeginDocument{\maketitle\thispagestyle{empty}\noindent}
\newcommand\meta[1]{$\langle\hbox{#1}\rangle$}
\newcommand\PaperTitle[1]{``\textit{#1}''}

\title{Response of review comments }
\author{Rudresh \and Somnath }
\date{\today}
\begin{document}

\begin{framed}
{\color{blue} the goal of this article}
\end{framed}

Text description for frame 1.

\begin{framed}
{\color{blue} the goal of this article}
\end{framed}
Text description for frame 2.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you have a MWE?

Comment: @samcarter MWE added

Comment: Your document is not compilable. `\title` is missing and the `framed` environment is unknown. Why do you not use `\newtcolorbox` right from the beginning?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer please check now

Comment: @rudreshdwivedi: There is still no `framed` package

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Please see now

Comment: There's also no need for `\ExplSyntaxOn...\ExplSyntaxOff` here.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer how do i enumerate in a fancy way?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer This is good. Can you please tell how to create the newtcolorbox Goal 1 or Goal 2 to be of same textwidth. It should not appear in whole line.

Comment: @rudreshdwivedi: Your question does not say that it should not appear in whole line. What do you mean by `the same textwidth`?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer First of all. Thanks for the answer. Sir, actually, you created the newtcolorbox  for Goal 1 and it took the whole linewidth whereas I need a smallbox under the frame i.e in the leftmost corner to just enumerate.

Comment: @rudreshdwivedi: Why did you not wrote that in your question?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I am sorry for that...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A suggestion:

A possible way is to use the `\newtcolorbox` command to define a `goal` framed box:

`\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{someframedbox}[1][]{some tcolorbox options, title={Goal \thetcbcounter}, #1}`

This provides a enumerated box with the usual `tcolorbox` facilities.

There's no point in defining a regular `environment` `reviewer-comment` first and then wrap `tcolorbox` around it.

The statements `\begin{reviewer-comment~}` are wrong, the `~` can't be there.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{microtype,xparse,tcolorbox}
\newenvironment{reviewer-comment}{}{}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\tcolorboxenvironment{reviewer-comment}{empty,
  left = 1em, top = 1ex, bottom = 1ex,
  borderline west = {2pt} {0pt} {black!20},
}
\NewDocumentEnvironment {response} { +m O{black!20} } {
  \IfValueT {#1} {
    \begin{reviewer-comment}
      \setlength\parindent{2em}
      \noindent
      \ttfamily #1
    \end{reviewer-comment}
  }
  \par\noindent\ignorespaces
} { \bigskip\par }

\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{someframedbox}[1][]{%
  colupper=blue,
  enhanced jigsaw,
  sharp corners,
  coltitle=white,
  colbacktitle=blue,
  colback=white,
  %attach boxed title to top left={yshift=1pt},
  %boxed title style={boxrule=0pt,sharp corners},
  title={Goal \thetcbcounter},
  #1
}


\NewDocumentCommand \Reviewer { m } {
  \section*{Comments~by~Reviewer~#1}
}

\title{How to annoy people by not providing a MWE}
\author{Mr. Gumby}
\AtBeginDocument{\maketitle\thispagestyle{empty}\noindent}

\begin{document}

\begin{response}{Stuff}
  Foo
\end{response}

\begin{someframedbox}
The goal of this article
\end{someframedbox}


Text description for frame 1.

\begin{someframedbox}
The goal of this article
\end{someframedbox}
Text description for frame 2.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for the article title.  I went back to the OP's prior edits to confirm that he was MWE-deficient.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: Only for the title? :-((((((

Comment: Well, the answer's pretty good, too...but that title!

Comment: @rudreshdwivedi: I don't think Steven did downvote your question (nor did I), but your question is unclear and you basically changed it with each comment you wrote ... what do you expect we should do with such posts? It allows for a billion of possible answers or of no answer ...

Comment: @rudreshdwivedi Christian is accurate in what he says.  I did not downvote your question; however, the utility of an MWE is indispensible, or else it leaves confusion, ambiguity, and often (for the OP), frustration at not getting a suitable answer.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Very very good +1.